# Chrome extension - CCRZ is not defined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, salesforce

Previously, I was pasting fragment of code (look script.js) to console and it was worked. This code manipulate DOM on Salesforce/CloudCraze page. Now I want the code to be executed after clicking on Chrome extension widget button.

The problem is: **'Uncaught ReferenceError: CCRZ is not defined'**. CCRZ isn't a library so I cannot fix the problem as I done with JQuery and Underscore.

The question is: how to fix this problem or how to inject this code using widget in another way? Thanks for help.

manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "CloudCraze Widget",
    "description": "CloudCraze Widget",
    "version": "1.0.0",

    "permissions": ["tabs", "<all_urls>"],

    "icons": {
        "16": "resources/icon.png",
        "48": "resources/icon.png",
        "128": "resources/icon.png"
    },

    "background": {
        "scripts": [
            "js/script.js"
        ],
        "persistent": true
    },

    "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "resources/icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
    }
}
```

main.js

```
function runSwitchjs() {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript({
    file: 'js/underscore.min.js'
    }, function(){
        chrome.tabs.executeScript({
            file: 'js/jquery.min.js'
        }, function(){
            chrome.tabs.executeScript({
            file: 'js/script.js'
        })
        }
    )}
    );
}

document.getElementById('showButton').addEventListener('click', runSwitchjs);
```

script.js

```
function doSth() { 
    // logic
} 

$.each(CCRZ.dynamicViews, function(view){ 
    doSth(); 
    // do sth else
});
```

Comment: You need to dig one level deeper to access a variable defined in the page context: [Insert code into the page context using a content script](//stackoverflow.com/a/9517879)

Comment: Thanks for your help. Work nearly as I expected.